# Partial and duplicate records while sqoop import

Tags: sqoop, duplicate-data

Sqoop import is resulting in duplicate/partial records when we are using the following setting

- `--query` - Custom Query
- `--split-by` - Non-integer column (char)
- `--num-mappers` - More than 2

> Verified the source data count say 1000 records
>
> Verified the import data count say 1923 records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `split-by` and field is non integer .

Sqoop uses TextSplitter  which provides a warning as follows :

```
WARN db.TextSplitter: If your database sorts in a case-insensitive order, this may result in a partial import or duplicate records

WARN db.TextSplitter: You are strongly encouraged to choose an integral split column.
```

- solution 1: use single mapper or 2
- solution 2: use rank function in the query and use the `--split-by` on the rank field
- solution 3: sort the `--split-by` field in ascending order in the query

Comment: could you explain why may result in a partial import or duplicate records? could you give me an example?

Comment: It is the implementation of the splitter in which the range sometimes overlap which gives duplicate . On the other hand sometimes range doesn’t include the value