# What are the conditions duplicate or partial records occur while "Apache Sqoop import" using TextSplitter?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sqoop

We use Apache Sqoop data import from MySQL tables. But occur duplicate records.
We are using the following.

`--query` - Custom Query
`--split-by` - VARCHAR column CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
`--num-mappers` - 5

relate-question:[Partial and duplicate records while sqoop import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197895/partial-and-duplicate-records-while-sqoop-import)

TextSplitter may result in a partial import or duplicate records, but we think `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` not satisfy *`sorts in a case-insensitive order`* condition.

This problem has other conditions OR is not TextSplitter problem?

Comment: We use `PREFIX_00000001` ･･･ `PREFIX_99999999`, and `PREFIX_a0000000, PREFIX_a0000001, ` ･･･ `PREFIX_j9999999, PREFIX_k0000000` for `--split-by` column. Total 200 million data.

Comment: Sorry. I posted incorrect `--num-mappers`. That is not 4 but 5.

Comment: I also wonder why, Did you get key?